# Using pandas and json_normalize to flatten nested JSON API response

Tags: python, json, pandas, surveymonkey

I have a deeply nested JSON that I am trying to turn into a Pandas Dataframe using [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

A [generic sample](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses-bulk) of the JSON data I'm working with looks looks like this (I've added context of what I'm trying to do at the bottom of the post):

```
{
    "per_page": 2,
    "total": 1,
    "data": [{
            "total_time": 0,
            "collection_mode": "default",
            "href": "https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/responses/5007154325",
            "custom_variables": {
                "custvar_1": "one",
                "custvar_2": "two"
            },
            "custom_value": "custom identifier for the response",
            "edit_url": "https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/",
            "analyze_url": "https://www.surveymonkey.com/analyze/browse/",
            "ip_address": "",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "id": "103332310",
                    "questions": [{
                            "answers": [{
                                    "choice_id": "3057839051"
                                }
                            ],
                            "id": "319352786"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "44783164",
                    "questions": [{
                            "id": "153745381",
                            "answers": [{
                                    "text": "some_name"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "44783183",
                    "questions": [{
                            "id": "153745436",
                            "answers": [{
                                    "col_id": "1087201352",
                                    "choice_id": "1087201369",
                                    "row_id": "1087201362"
                                }, {
                                    "col_id": "1087201353",
                                    "choice_id": "1087201373",
                                    "row_id": "1087201362"
                                }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                }
            ],
            "date_modified": "1970-01-17T19:07:34+00:00",
            "response_status": "completed",
            "id": "5007154325",
            "collector_id": "50253586",
            "recipient_id": "0",
            "date_created": "1970-01-17T19:07:34+00:00",
            "survey_id": "105723396"
        }
    ],
    "page": 1,
    "links": {
        "self": "https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/123456/responses/bulk?page=1&per_page=2"
    }
}
```

I'd like to end up with a dataframe that contains the question_id, page_id, response_id, and response data like this:

```
    choice_id      col_id      row_id       text   question_id       page_id      response_id
0  3057839051         NaN         NaN        NaN     319352786     103332310       5007154325
1         NaN         NaN         NaN  some_name     153745381      44783164       5007154325
2  1087201369  1087201352  1087201362        NaN     153745436      44783183       5007154325
3  1087201373  1087201353  1087201362        NaN     153745436      44783183       5007154325
```

I can get close by running the following code (Python 3.6):

```
df = json_normalize(data=so_survey_responses['data'], record_path=['pages', 'questions'], meta='id', record_prefix ='question_')
print(df)
```

Which returns:

```
                                    question_answers question_id          id
0                      [{'choice_id': '3057839051'}]   319352786  5007154325
1                            [{'text': 'some_name'}]   153745381  5007154325
2  [{'col_id': '1087201352', 'choice_id': '108720...   153745436  5007154325
```

But if I try to run json_normalize at a deeper nest and keep the 'question_id' data from the above result, I can only get the page_id values to return, not true question_id values:

```
answers_df = json_normalize(data=so_survey_responses['data'], record_path=['pages', 'questions', 'answers'], meta=['id', ['questions', 'id'], ['pages', 'id']])
print(answers_df)
```

Returns:

```
    choice_id      col_id      row_id       text          id questions.id   pages.id
0  3057839051         NaN         NaN        NaN  5007154325    103332310  103332310
1         NaN         NaN         NaN  some_name  5007154325     44783164   44783164
2  1087201369  1087201352  1087201362        NaN  5007154325     44783183   44783183
3  1087201373  1087201353  1087201362        NaN  5007154325     44783183   44783183
```

A complicating factor may be that all the above (question_id, page_id, response_id) are 'id:' in the JSON data.

I'm sure this is possible, but I can't get there. Any examples of how to do this?

**Additional context:**
I'm trying to create a dataframe of [SurveyMonkey API response output](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#quick-start-guide-two-common-use-cases).

My long term goal is to re-create the ["all responses" excel sheet that their export service provides](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Export-Examples).

I plan to do this by getting the response dataframe set up (above), and then use [.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to match responses with their [survey structure API output](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-details).

I've found the SurveyMonkey API pretty lackluster at providing useful output, but I'm new to Pandas so it's probably on me.

Comment: Did you ever succeed in formatting the responses from the Survey Monkey API in a ways that (even vaguely) resembles the Excel sheet from their export service? If so, would you save my week by sharing the code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to modify the `meta` parameter of your last option, and, if you want to rename columns to be exactly the way you want, you could do it with `rename`:

```
answers_df = json_normalize(data=so_survey_responses['data'],
                        record_path=['pages', 'questions', 'answers'],
                        meta=['id', ['pages', 'questions', 'id'], ['pages', 'id']])\
.rename(index=str,
        columns={'id': 'response_id', 'pages.questions.id': 'question_id', 'pages.id': 'page_id'})
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in a completely generic way using `json_normalize()`. You can use the `record_path` and `meta` arguments to indicate how you want the JSON to be processed.

However, you can use the [flatten package](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten) to flatten your deeply nested JSON and then convert that to a Pandas dataframe. The page has [example usage](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten#usage-with-pandas) of how to flatten a deeply-nested JSON and convert to a Pandas dataframe.